# JSTL Spring Boot - Bean property 'email' is not readable or has an invalid getter method

Tags: java, spring, jstl

I am fairly new to using Spring Boot and JSTL. I am currently trying to implement something in my view where I can select multiple checkboxes and send the data over to my controller to operate on. I think I have done everything correctly but can't seem to find the root of the problem here. Can someone please help? Getting the following error:

> 021-02-09 17:49:45.227 ERROR 16216 --- [nio-8080-exec-6]
> o.s.web.servlet.tags.form.CheckboxTag    : Invalid property 'email' of
> bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'email' is not
> readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the
> getter match the parameter type of the setter?
>
> org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid
> property 'email' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property
> 'email' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the
> return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?     at
> org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:625)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]   at
> org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:615)
> ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]

My Controller:

```
package com.bizlinks.mainapp.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import java.util.List;

import com.bizlinks.mainapp.models.Lead;
import com.bizlinks.mainapp.repository.UserRepository;



@Controller
public class AdminController {
    
    @Autowired // This means to get the bean called userRepository
    //Which is auto-generated by Spring, we will use it to handle the data
    private UserRepository userRepository;  
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String List(Model model) {
        
        
        List<Lead> leads = userRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("leads", leads);
                
        
        return "admin";
        
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "admin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String deleteLead(@ModelAttribute("leads")List<Lead> leads){
        
        for(int i =0; i< leads.size();i++) {
            
            System.out.println(leads.get(i).getEmail());
        }
        
        return "admin";
    }
}
```

My model:

```
package com.bizlinks.mainapp.models;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "leads")
public class Lead {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "surName")
    private String surName;
    
    @Column(name ="phone")
    private String phone;

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setSurName(String surName) {
        this.surName = surName;
    }

    public String getSurName() {
        return surName;
    }
    
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
}
```

My view body:

```
<body>

        
    <nav class="nav nav-fill">
        
      <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>

      
    </nav>
    
    <div class="container-fluid con">
            <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Surname</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                    </tr>
                    
                  <form:form action="admin" modelAttribute="leads">
                     <c:forEach items="${leads}" var="item">                    
                        <tr>
                                 
                            <td><c:out value="${item.email}"/></td>                     
                            <td><c:out value="${item.firstName}"/></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${item.surName}"/></td>                       
                            <td><c:out value="${item.phone}"/></td>
                            <form:checkbox path="email" value="${item.email}"/> 
                            
                        </tr>                     
                   </c:forEach>
                   
                   <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
                   
                  </form:form>
                   
                
            </table>
    </div>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you want to check in the checkbox? Can you add more details?

Comment: I want to use the checkbox to select the whole item in the row, so I can transfer the data to my backend and manipulate it.